# Image does not appear in container until HotReload is triggered

Tags: android, flutter, image, dart, containers

I'm trying to load an image and show it in a container but when selecting image , the container doesn't update. It's like my setState doesn't work inside my navigator widget.

*Can someone help me? :/*

**Here is my image upload code:**

```
    File? _image;
  final _picker = ImagePicker();
  // Implementing the image picker
  Future<void> _openImagePicker() async {
    final XFile? pickedImage =
        await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      setState(() {
        _image = File(pickedImage.path);
      });
    }
  }
```

**Here where I'm trying to show the image**

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return Material(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 20,
              left: 20,
              right: 20,
              // prevent the soft keyboard from covering text fields
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 20),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: _titleController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Titulo'),
              ),
              TextField(
                keyboardType:
                    const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                controller: _descController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Descrição',
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: _openImagePicker,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.image,
                  )),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                child: _image != null
                    ? Image.file(_image!, fit: BoxFit.fill)
                    : const Text('Please select an image'),
              ),
```

Result image :

[image: resulting screen]

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you are showing image in wrong way. when you call `Navigator.push` you leave the current context tree to new one so setstate wont update image because that state replace by new one.

what you could do is that you create new stateless or statefull class and put your show image widget in that and wait for response to come from upload function and then navigate to that new class and pass image as argument.

Comment: I managed to make a class. But I can't get the image in this new class and show it there, do you have any tips, I'm new to development.